# dump of lists into csv export

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add column headers and then export the following to csv.
But when I export the list, I get the last line with each of the characters in columns.

This is the output:

[image: Current output of list]

If I implement df=pd.DataFrame([d])
I get the following :

[image]

Code that creates this list is as follows

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(s,'lxml')
soup.prettify()
for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
s=anchor['href']
if 'bus' in s:
    urlparse(s)
    path = urlparse(s).path[1:]
    parts = path.split('/')
    d= parts[2:4]
    df=pd.DataFrame(d)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with the actual data. Screenshots of data, code, and errors do not belong on SO.

Comment: @DYZ but I am unable to get the data to csv hence why I am asking the question. I cannot copy paste the results for some reason from the command prompt. Its a lot of data by the way and its just a small fraction of it.

Comment: What type of object is `d`? Why are you passing it to `pd.DataFrame` as a list (e.g. in `[]`). Have you tried `pd.DataFrame(d)`?

Comment: I get something like this if I do without the []
alon-De-Coiffure-Pour-Hommes-Laurier
                   0
0          Longueuil
1  King-s-Barbershop
                   0
0          Longueuil
1  King-s-Barbershop
                   0
0          Longueuil
1  King-s-Barbershop
                   0
0          Longueuil
1  King-s-Barbershop
                   0
0          Longueuil
1  King-s-Barbershop
                  0
0         Longueuil
1  Kings-Barbershop
                  0
0         Longueuil
1  Kings-Barbershop

Comment: I will add the code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that for each iteration of the loop you're creating a *new* `DataFrame`; whereas what I imagine you probably want is a single `DataFrame` with *all* of the values for `d`. Try the below:

```
# Instantiate an empty list to collect values of `d` for each iteration
d_values = []

soup=BeautifulSoup(s,'lxml')
soup.prettify()
for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    s=anchor['href']

    if 'bus' in s:
        urlparse(s)
        path = urlparse(s).path[1:]
        parts = path.split('/')
        d = parts[2:4]

        # Append `d` to your list, creating a list of lists
        d_values.append(d)

# Once your loop is done, create a DataFrame from your list of lists
df = pd.DataFrame(d_values, columns=['col1name','col2name'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! really appreciate your help!